# How to Fade in a DIV After Scrolling Down, then Fade it Out at the Bottom

Tags: javascript, scroll, fadein, fadeout

I have a div that I want to fade in after the user scrolls 600px down the page. I have achieved this easily enough using the code below:

```
<script>
$(window).scroll(function(){
if($(window).scrollTop()>600){
$("#fade-in-area").fadeIn();
}else{
$("#fade-in-area").fadeOut();
}
});
</script>
```

I want the same div to fade out about 600 pixels from the bottom of the page. I have seen a couple other people trying to do this, but can't figure out how to have it both fade in, and fade out.

It should be pretty easy for a regular Javascript programmer I'd think.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
<script>
   $(window).scroll(function(){
       var leftToBottom = $(document).height() - $(window).height() - $(window).scrollTop();
       var distanceFromTop = $(window).scrollTop();
       if( distanceFromTop > 600 && !$("#fade-in-area").is(":visible") 
          && leftToBottom > 600) {
            $("#fade-in-area").fadeIn();
       }else if($("#fade-in-area").is(":visible") && (distanceFromTop < 600 || leftToBottom < 600)){
            $("#fade-in-area").fadeOut();
      }
   });
</script>
```

It should fadeOut a div if there is less than 600 px left to scroll bottom.

Comment: This works with a couple exceptions.

When you scroll to the bottom, it fades out like it should, but if you are within the bottom 600px of the window and scroll again, it will fade in and out again, if that makes sense.

If you are within the bottom 600px of the page, any time you scroll up or down it fades in and out.

Also, if you scroll down 600px from the top, it fades in, but if you scroll back up to the top, it no longer fades out.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try updated code. Should work better. Still not sure if completely correct as I have not tested that.

Comment: That does it! Thanks so much! :)